# Why is dojo.isIE showing 8 in IE9 console?

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-9

I have turned off compatibility mode for IE9 but dojo.isIE is still showing 8 in IE9.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: How did you turn off compat mode? Do you have any meta-tags?

Comment: If you open the debugger (F12), what mode does it say Ie is running under?

Comment: I turned off compatibility mode by "Tools -> Compatibility View Settings" and unchecking compability view check boxes. On the debugger it says "Browser Mode: IE9". I don't have any meta tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There was a meta tag somewhere that was defining IE8 document mode. The meta tag was out of my sight.